ffmpeg causes do loop to exit after first iteration
I have this loop to find mp4 files that I want to convert to webm.
find "./$1" -type f -iname "*.mp4" | while IFS== read -r f; do
        echo "found: $f"
        fn=$( echo "$f" | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev )
        fWebm="${fn}.webm"
        #ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 128k -c:a libopus "$fWebm"
        if [ -f "$fWebm" ]; then
                echo "removing $f"
                #rm "$f"
        else
                echo "not removing $f"
        fi
        echo "Done."
done

If I uncomment the ffmpeg line then it converts the first video then quits.
Why?
How can I get it to continue with the rest of the files?

My guess in such situations is always that find | while read breaks in surprising ways. That's why we usually strongly discourage doing that, and recommend using find … -exec … or, even better here, simply not using find but globbing; you can replace your whole find … ; do line with a simple shopt -s nullglob globstar nocaseglob; for f in **/*.mp4 ; do.

ah, and by the way, your fn= is creative, but a) should be in quotes "$(…)" (!) and b) setting shopt -s nocasematch at the beginning and doing fWebm="${f/%.mp4/.webm} is probably a bit easier on the mind of the reader.

Also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089 . This is particular to ffmpeg.

@Marcus, fn=$(foo) is exactly the same as fn="$(foo)", since a (scalar) assignment isn't subject to splitting and globbing anyway. (Barring bugs which e.g. Bash has had in some corner cases.)

find | while read f is fine as long as the filenames are nice. find | while IFS= read -r f is better (it should pretty much leave newlines in filenames as the only issue). But setting IFS== seems odd, it would split on equal signs and that doesn't seem too useful here.

@ilkkachu ah, you're right. I had the case where $var amounts to something like something another=thing in my mind, but you're right, that won't get split in foo=$var.
